# Locally deleting folder while ignoring its presence in the repo

Tags: tortoisesvn

To keep it simple I will use a simplistic example.

I have a versioned folder A and there are two more folders X and Y and a file f. X and Y may contain any number and depth of files and folders. So the tree looks like this:

```
A
|-X
| |-[...]
|
|-Y
| |-[...]
|
|-f
```

Now I have A with all contents fully recursively checked out on my disk.

After a while it shows that I don't need Y any more and I want to delete it from my disk and TortoiseSVN to no longer check it out again or update it. I just need A and f.

But Y should reseide in the repo as usual, unaffected by my local decision.

So how do I accomplish that by means of TortoiseSVN?

If I just delete the folder Y then TortoiseSVN will show me in the commit-box on next occasion that Y is mission and wants me to commit this, which will lead to Y being deleted in the repo as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to ignore a whole part of a directory tree like that in TortoiseSVN. I think the simplest solution would just be to only check out the parts of the repository that you need, i.e. instead of checking out from the root (A), check out X instead into its own folder.